# Madrid Airport changing terminals, do I need a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, airports

I am an Indian citizen. I am flying from Toronto to New Delhi. I have two transits: one at Lisbon airport and the second one at Madrid airport.

While the Consulate of Portugal has assured me that I do not need an airport transit visa during my 2 hours stay in Lisbon airport, I did not get a definitive answer from the consulate of Spain in Toronto.

At Madrid airport, I need to make a transfer from Terminal 2 to Terminal 1.

Does anyone here know whether I need to pass through immigration while making this transition in Madrid and if so, do I need a Schengen visa for that?

Answer (score 10):

Since you are transiting in both Lisbon *and* Madrid, you will be **entering the Schengen Area** and not just transiting. Therefore, as soon as no *visa-free travel* is allowed to Indian citizens, you will need a regular Schengen short stay visa, regardless of the terminal situation in Madrid.

As you are entering through Portugal, you should apply for such a visa at the consulate of Portugal.

The consulate of Portugal likely told you the contrary because they didn't realize you will be going to Spain next, and not directly to India.

You should now decide whether you actually want to go through the visa application process, or maybe just rebook your flights such that you only transit at one Schengen Airport (e. g. YYZ-FRA-DEL). Look at the costs for the visa and for rebooking the flights before making your decision.

Comment: I have amended the answer adding a bit of detail (Indians can't travel Schengen visa-free or with the so-called *airport visa* like a list of other countries). However, I'll not be amending another part which I would like to discuss. The OP could apply at either Portugal or Spain, because AFAIK one should apply at the consulate of the country where the traveler plans to stay longer (e.g. 5 days Spain, 5 Switzerland, 10 days Latvia, Latvia is the winner). This information could be useful according to appointment queues

Answer (score 8):

You need a Schengen type C short stay visa for this itinerary.

The terminal change in Madrid isn't relevant; the fact that you are entering the Schengen area at Lisbon and exiting Schengen in Madrid is the important bit. To do this, you need to have the regular Schengen visa.

Comment: As I understand the question, OP is not traveling between Lisbon and Madrid, but transiting twice (perhaps once on the outbound journey from India to Canada and the other time on the way back).

Comment: @dbkk The question only mentions one, one-way flight.

Comment: @dbkk I think the one-way interpretation is correct, and [such itineraries do exist](https://i.imgur.com/RaoEBVg.png).

Comment: I am transiting twice during my journey from Canada to India, which means I am traveling between Lisbon to Madrid..

Comment: @pankaj While your question asked only about a trip from Canada to India, it is indeed true that if you take a similar but reversed itinerary from India back to Canada, you will need a valid Schengen visa for that journey as well.

Comment: Thanks, I went to the consulate of Portugal yesterday. I told them about the situation that I will be entering the Schengen Area at Lisbon and exiting Schengen in Madrid, but they refused to accept the application and told me to apply for the visa at the consulate of Spain. I went to the Spanish consulate and they approved my visa application. I will be going there on Friday to collect the passport. However they did not tell which type of visa have they approved. If they give me an airport transit visa, would it be a problem since that visa is different from the Schengen Type C visa.

Comment: Agree with others that if you're entering Schengen once when travelling to India, then on the way back to Canada you enter Schengen the second time.. you would need a dual/multi entry visa.

Comment: @pankaj It is good to hear that you got the visa, but it is very strange to hear that Portugal rejected your application. It has always been the advice in such situations to apply for the visa in the Schengen member state which is the main destination of the trip, or if there is no main destination, then the member state of entry. So we are all confused to hear that Portugal rejected it and Spain processed your application and approved it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had to cancel the the trip since the consulate of Spain gave me an airport transit visa and not the schengen short term visa, which was required in this case. The consulate of Portugal messed it up completely since they were the ones who were obliged to give me schengen short term visa, but they kept on denying my request and asking me to go to the consulate of Spain again and again.

Comment: @pankaj Hmm, that really shouldn't have happened. As Michael said, the rules are actually pretty clear in that Portugal should have been responsible, and regardless, the Spanish consulate should have known that a transit visa would be worthless to you. Did you actually show the consulates your exact itinerary and does it look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/RaoEBVg.png)? What reason did the Portuguese consulate give you for rejecting your application and referring you to Spain?

Comment: @Mophotla Yes the itinerary looked exactly like the one you are showing. I showed the consulates my itinerary but the consulate of Portugal was adamant that they cannot give me the Schengen short term visa and kept on insisting that I need to go to the Spanish consulate and the consulate of Spain asked me to request Portuguese consulate to issue me the visa. Finally, when nothing worked out and I was on a merry-go-round, the Spanish consulate issued me an airport transit visa. The Portuguese messed up the situation completely due to their incompetent staff.